# Why do I have to be outside the package's folder to properly execute the class file?

Tags: java, package, javac

(Note: I know I am not using standard naming conventions here. The names are simply for the purpose of simplicity.)

I have a file called 'PackageTest.java'. It's sole purpose is to print a line to the console saying, "This works!". It belongs to a package named main. In my console I execute the command:

```
javac -d . PackageTest.java
```

This creates a new directory (folder) called main, which contains the class file named 'PackageTest.main'. I am CD'd into it's parent directory, and I execute the following command:

```
java main.PackageTest
```

And the console then reads:

```
This works!
```

So the file executed. That's good. Now I CD into the 'main' folder. I execute the command:

```
java main.PackageTest
```

Only to get the result:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main.PackageTest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.PackageTest
```

So I try this command:

```
java PackageTest
```

And now I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class PackageTest
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main/PackageTest (wrong name: 
PackageTest)
```

Why do I have to be outside of the directory to allow the file to execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package (and folder) are semantically meaningful. You **can** specify the classpath, if you use an absolute path you can move anywhere in your tree and still run the code. It's also possible to use a relative path. Like,

```
java -cp .. main.PackageTest
```